# How to find matching rows in two tables, doesn't exist in second

Tags: mysql, woocommerce

I'm using woocommerce and a plugin that saves the cost of products. I'm trying to find out which products don't have this info registered.

So I have two SQL that work fine at the moment, one that returns all the products, and another one that returns only the products that have the cost info.

I'm trying to make a minus so to get a list of products without the cost info. Problem is that the query doesn't work. I tried different things:

```
SELECT WP.post_title
FROM wp_posts as WP, wp_postmeta as PM
WHERE PM.meta_key='_posr_cost_of_good'
and PM.post_id=WP.ID
and WP.post_status='publish'
and WP.post_type='product' NOT in (
    SELECT WP.post_title
    FROM wp_posts as WP
    where  WP.post_status='publish'
    and WP.post_type='product' )
```

The above returns zero results.

The next query using MINUS gives an error:

```
SELECT WP.post_title
FROM wp_posts as WP
where WP.post_status='publish'
and WP.post_type='product'
MINUS
SELECT WP.post_title
FROM wp_posts as WP, wp_postmeta as PM
WHERE PM.meta_key='_posr_cost_of_good'
and PM.post_id=WP.ID
and WP.post_status='publish'
and WP.post_type='product'
```

The error is:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'MINUS (SELECT WP.post_title FROM wp_posts as WP, wp_postmeta as PM WHERE P' at line 4"

Both parts of the MINUS query work fine. The first gives 482 results, and the second bit gives 330 rows in the result.

Answer (score 0):

The standard efficient way of finding rows *without* matching data elsewhere is to use a left join and filter for joined nulls.

I'm pretty sure this will work:

```
SELECT WP.post_title
FROM wp_posts as WP
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta as PM ON PM.post_id=WP.ID
    AND PM.meta_key='_posr_cost_of_good'
WHERE WP.post_status='publish'
AND PM.post_id IS NULL
```

Note that you must use proper joins to do this (which you should be using anyway - that syntax is over 20 years old now).

Note that any conditions on the joined table must be in the *join* condition (not the where clause) - eg, in this case `PM.meta_key='_posr_cost_of_good'`. If you put that in the where clause, you'd force it to an *inner* join.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, manage to get it to work with the following: 
SELECT WP.post_title, CONCAT('https://www.tudosaudavel.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=',WP.ID,'&action=edit')
FROM wp_posts as WP
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta as PM ON PM.post_id=WP.ID
    AND PM.meta_key='_posr_cost_of_good'
WHERE WP.post_status='publish' and WP.post_type='product'
AND PM.post_id IS NULL

Answer (score 0):

You said the first bit gave 482 and second one 330. 
Can you try to do a distinct count of values produced by first bit and second. 
May be, the correct answer is 0 records difference! 
Just a guess.

Comment: Actually it gave the same answer with the distinct. And defintelly it has many items without the cost info, just can do the search one by one, so a minus or any other way would be best.